# AWS RDS can't be viewed from msstudio

Tags: amazon-rds

I logined as the RDS master username and password , but not sure why I have "select permission issue" encounter when open the table in ms studio . This is already the master account of RDS , have no clues

Comment: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'projects', database 'hycdb', schema 'dbo  , this previously works ,  but i decided not to use AWS someday , then delete some of the setting like EC2 , not sure if it matters